# Can you make a script pass a command inside of an application?

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql
```

I see that the rest of the script after line two is run after exiting MySQL. Would it be possible to add a command which should be used inside of mysql? Say I want the script to run MySQL and issue a "show tables;" command, would that be doable?

Comment: Depends on the cli options of the appilcation.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `mysql`, you can pass commands as arguments using the `-e` command-line option, or via standard input - using a here-document for example. So either

```
mysql -u dbUser -pdbPass -e 'use mydb; show tables;'
```

or

```
mysql -u dbUser -pdbPass << EOF
use mydb;
show tables;
EOF
```

(where `dbUser`, `dbPass`, `mydb` are replaced as appropriate).